# Converting PDB file to ANSYS

Tags: pdp

I'm new in Python. I'm modelling Zirconia nanotubes. Have generated the structure in PDB and want to export the file to ANSYS. The codes below was written for Python:

```
 node_value = 0
 file = open('C:\\xyz\\test.pdb', 'r')
 igot = file.readlines()
 output_file = open('C:\\xyz\\nodes.txt', "a") # needs input for distinct file 
 utput_file.write('/PREP7'+"\n") #open pre-processing menu
 for line in igot:
 if line.find("ATOM") > -1:
        node_value = node_value + 1
        nv = str(node_value)
        xyz =  line.split()
        #print kv,",", xyz[6], ",", xyz[7], ",", xyz[8] 
        line_i = "N" + ', '+ nv + ', ' + xyz[6] + ', ' + xyz[7] +', '+ xyz[8]+ "\n"
        print (line_i)
        output_file.write(line_i)
```

I got an error message:File "c:\xyz\test.py", line 2, in 
  file = open('C:\xyz\test.pdb', 'r')

builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\xyz\test.pdb'

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bold guess: There is no file 'C:\xyz\test.pdb'

Comment: I have created the file, but got another error message:  File "None", line 2, in <module>
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: truncated \xXX escape (<wingdb_compile>, line 2)

Answer (score -1):

upload the .pdb file to python notebook and directly replace the file location with file name.